# Specific Column is not showing up, when it should?

Tags: sql, sorting, count

I don't know what's going on with my code here.  I am trying to return the highest number of calls received by particular phone numbers, and find the top 7 numbers by calls received, but I am only getting the count column in my results.  The code is:

```
SELECT COUNT (call_id) FROM call_test
GROUP BY receiver_id
ORDER BY COUNT(call_id) DESC
LIMIT 7;
```

But all it is returning is:

```
COUNT(call_id)
3
2
2
2
2
1
1
```

I think my code is right, but how do you show the particular numbers that correspond to the respective counts?  This is SQLPro for MAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it as simple as including the number in the `select`?

```
SELECT receiver_id, COUNT(call_id)
FROM call_test
GROUP BY receiver_id
ORDER BY COUNT(call_id) DESC
LIMIT 7;
```